# SignalA (SignalR Android Client) not working with SignalR 2.1.2

Tags: android, signalr

I tried to use latest version of SignalA with latest version of SignalR 2.1.2, but the SignalA library throw exception of protocol verification.

how can I fix this problem ?
also what should I do if I want to contribute to SignalA project and update it to last SignalR version? is there any documentation I should read?

Answer (score 0):

The SignalA client git repo doesn't seem to have updated from April 2014. I suggest using the SignalR java client backed by SignalR official team. It is uptodate and working. You can get it from https://github.com/SignalR/java-client

Comment: the problem with that Client is that it needs Android 4.4.2 which is too new for current available devices.